# In my thesis, do all sources I've cited need to be mentioned in the Literature Review?

Tags: citations, thesis, masters, literature-review

I'm writing a Masters Thesis and am just not sure if every source I've cited in my thesis, I need to disuss in the Literature Review?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE! It is not clear to me when you say "every source I've cited in my thesis": do you mean that you listed some sources in the bibliography first, and then are asking if you need to discuss them in the lit review? Or are you asking if there is a source that you have mentioned and cited elsewhere in the thesis, if it needs to be discussed again in the lit review? These are two different scenarios. Please edit your question to clarify which you mean.

Answer (score 6):

While you have to cite every source that you reference properly, you defenitely don't have to discuss every source in the literature review. Some sources you cite might only be needed for little things like an equation, a standard used for testing, or a confirmation of an hypothesis you make, market projections, single statistical results, etc. Other sources might be slightly off-topic but still relevant for a small part of the thesis.

Limit the sources discussed in the literature review to those that fit there.